# stopping css onhover shifting all other blocks around

Tags: html, css

I am using the `hover` event over a `<div>` to make an additional description about the element appear.

The problem is that when you hover on a `<div>` it shifts the others around. Basically I would like everything else to stay in place and the word **blob** to just appear over the top of them.

Here is an example of a [jsfiddle outlining the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/FtH3e/)

How can I change it so the other blocks do not shift?

Comment: Are you missing some .js in your fiddle?

Comment: no ... its the text jsfiddlie outlining the problem

Comment: look at your fiddle it does nothing different when you hover on anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `extra_info` needs to be positioned absolute to the `block` div

```
.link{
    position:relative;
    margin : 2em 0em 2em 1.5em;
    float: left;
    width: 10.4em;
    min-height: 17em; 
    max-height: 18.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0em 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em; 
    background-color: #276277;
}

.block { position:relative; float:left; }

.extra_info{
    z-index: 900;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    display: none;
    width: 275px;
    background: #FFFFBC;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

Also, I do believe you need to do this with jquery

```
$('.link').hover(function() {
    // show the box
    $(this).siblings('.extra_info').toggle();
});
```

Here is a **[complete demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FtH3e/3/)**

Here is a **[demo where the extra_info is above each parent div](http://jsfiddle.net/FtH3e/4/)**

Comment: The demo looks awesome thanks! Exact functionality I was looking for. My only concern is why do I need to use jquery ie. why doesn't this seem to work using ccs hover instead

Comment: There is no way to specify which `.extra_info` gets displayed.  CSS doesn't hold that type of logic

Comment: okay awesome thats good to know... this concept has been buggin me for a while  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an underscore.

```
<div class="extra info">
```

should be

```
<div class="extra_info">
```

Comment: +1 to remove the downvote, he is correct his jsfiddle was a bit sloppy

Comment: Thank you Jon. Correcting the classname made the divs stop moving. The starting post didn't point out that the other divs should be aligned on top of the parent. That's why I didn't look any futher.